# keyerror panda+jupiter notebook with a csv file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

i found a csv file on kaggle so i downloaded it to learn on it ,i imported the panda module then read the file using it then i only kept the salaries and salary currencies columns then tried to get the highest and lowest salary with the currency being USD so i tried using loc but it came up with an error that looks like this :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 2
      1 df.head(10)
----> 2 df=df.loc[df['salary_currency']=="USD"]
      3 max_salary=df['salary'].max()
      4 min_salary=df['salary'].min()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1112, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
   1109     return self._values[key]
   1111 elif key_is_scalar:
-> 1112     return self._get_value(key)
   1114 # Convert generator to list before going through hashable part
   1115 # (We will iterate through the generator there to check for slices)
   1116 if is_iterator(key):

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1228, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1225     return self._values[label]
   1227 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1228 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1230 if is_integer(loc):
   1231     return self._values[loc]

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py:417, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key)
    415         raise KeyError(key) from err
...
--> 417     raise KeyError(key)
    418 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    419 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'salary_currency'
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_csv('ds_salaries.csv')
df=Data[['salary_currency','salary']]
df=df.loc[df['salary_currency']=="USD"]
max_salary=df['salary'].max()
min_salary=df['salary'].min()
print(max_salary,"\n",min_salary,"\n",df)
```

THIS IS THE LAST DATA FRAME BEFORE USING LOC:

```
salary_currency salary
0   EUR 80000
1   USD 30000
2   USD 25500
3   USD 175000
4   USD 120000
... ... ...
3750    USD 412000
3751    USD 151000
3752    USD 105000
3753    USD 100000
3754    INR 7000000
3755 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: Does ```salary_currency``` exist in your dataframe?  What's your sample like?

Comment: THIS IS THE DATA FRAME;
```salary_currency salary
0 EUR 80000
1 USD 30000
2 USD 25500
3 USD 175000
4 USD 120000
... ... ...
3750 USD 412000
3751 USD 151000
3752 USD 105000
3753 USD 100000
3754 INR 7000000
3755 rows × 2 columns```

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: LOOK AT THE POST

Comment: not super familiar, but why is it ```df = Data[[...]]```?

Comment: SHOULD I TRY TO NAME IT DF FROM THE START??

Comment: I TRIED IT AND IT WORKED,TYSM

Comment: sorry,caps, tysm i really appreciate your help, sorry for wasting your time on such a simple problem

Comment: I think you can do df = pd.read_csv('ds_salaries.csv', usecols=['salary_currency','salary'])

Comment: tysm , that will help me making the code a bit smaller and readable

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can see that the code you provided is not correpsonding to the code your running. Error occurs on line 2. I assume you're using a notebook and thus the order you run you're cells are important. Either give us the cells or try to copy the code you prived in a single cell and run that.

Comment: tysm for letting me know, i will be aware of that the next time i post a question on data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

someone helped me fixing this in the comments,the issue was so simple and dumb
i has to use df from the start instead of using `Data` then saying `df=Data[[...]]` so the right one should be `df = df[[...]]` in the third line and `df` instead of `Data` in the second line and it worked like that, a simple problem like that made the whole code wrong , this is an example of the why is the computer dumb because with the simplest mistakes the whole code doesn't work

Comment: This shouldn't matter in the code you provided, I think you should take a look at how notebooks work, the order in which you run cell matter!

Comment: Furthermore read_csv aslo has an argument usecols where you can specify the columns you want, this removing the whole df = df[[selected columns]] line. reducing the data you import and reducing the risk of errors. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: but somehow i don't have the error anymore after doing this, i see what u mean , the variable is already changed to df so it shouldn't really matter so idk what is the difference but it somehow does work now so ty

Comment: yeah someone said that in the comments too and i changed it and deleted the second block so ty